# How do I create partition in Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

I have a 2TB hard disk with Ubuntu 14.04 . Some 1.5 TB is used . I did not create any partitions during installation time of Ubuntu 13.10 . I upgraded to 14.04 but after upgrading there are some hang/crash problems . How to I create seperate parition like C: drive in Windows and other drive for just my data ( videos etc ) without losing data . After this I want to perform clean installation of 14.04.1 .

Here is output of `sudo parted -l`

```
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi) 
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B 
Partition Table: msdos 

Number    Start    End       Size    Type       File system     Flags 
1         1049kB   2048MB    2047MB  primary    linux-swap(v1)  boot 
2         2049MB   2000GB    1998GB  extended 
5         2049MB   32.4GB    30.3GB  logical    ext4 
6         32.4GB   2000GB    1968GB  logical    ext4
```

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo parted -l` in your question.

Comment: Can you not just install Ubuntu in the partition you currently have ubuntu installed in ? Go to live CD/USB and when installing choose erase Ubuntu 14.04 and reinstall

Comment: Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  2048MB  2047MB  primary   linux-swap(v1)  boot
 2      2049MB  2000GB  1998GB  extended
 5      2049MB  32.4GB  30.3GB  logical   ext4
 6      32.4GB  2000GB  1968GB  logical   ext4

Comment: @markkirby It says " This will delete all your Ubuntu programs , documents .... etc " .

Comment: Is there an option to upgrade 14.04 to 14.04 on the menu you chose something else

Comment: Here is the official documentation for this procedure, it should work https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Comment: Did you UNTICK the format box ?

Comment: I rather perform clean installtion . Upgrading has given me many problems . I want a seperate partition for OS files like C:\ in Windows .

Comment: Just to get this straight, you don't want anything on the hard disk right now? You want to completely remove Ubuntu, install 14.04.1 on a partition, and create another partition for all your other stuff. You don't want anything that's on the hard disk right now? Because I can see that you already have 2 partitions (30 GB and 1.9 TB).

Comment: No . I want the data . I don't have a backup of it. Infact this is my backup drive . I want some 50 GB for Ubuntu OS files like C: drive . And other drive like D:\ for my videos , music etc . How is this possible ? I did not even go to "Something Else" option during installation of Ubuntu 13.10 .

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you.

1 Boot to live CD/USB and choose install

2 Choose something else form the list to star partition manager

3 Highlight the HDD in the list, right click it

4 Choose mount point, set as /

5 THIS IS THE IMPORTANT STEP - UNTICK THE BOX THAT SAYS FORMAT

6 Now install

Choosing not to format the drive will leave your home folder untouched and thus your data intact.

You will have a clean install of 14.04 but with the home folder of your old install.

WARNING - REMOVE ALL CUSTOM THEMES ICONS ETC BEFOR INSTALLING OR YOU WONT SEE THE DESKTOP